# Can't dissolve edge without dissolving one next to it

Tags: edges

Sorry if this problem has a pretty obvious solution, but I only recently started using Blender, and I can't figure out why this is happening. I have an edge, which I separated into 2 edges (they also have a vertex separating them). However, whenever I try to dissolve only one of those 2 edges, the other one goes with it as well.

Before I dissolve an edge:

[image: Before:]

After I dissolve the bottom left vertical edge:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Problem with dissolve is that it needs to be applied with care as "crucial edges" can give effects like that when dissolved.